# onLoad function not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm  trying to set up a demo page for an API I'm developing at work, but I can't get my JavaScript to work. The JavaScript should poll on my server to check if the elaboration has ended and then perform the necessary operations to get the result on the browser, but I keep getting this error:

> Failed to clear temp storage: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources. SecurityError

After the first time I decided to simplify my code, cutting off calls until I got it working and the add up. Currently my function looks like this, but I still get the same error (I cleared the browser's cache, so it is not executing old versions):

```
function getStatus(){
    window.alert("Prova");
}
```

It should execute when a div is loaded:

```
<div id="LoaderImage" onload="getStatus()">
    ...
</div>
```

Since I can see the loading gif inside the div I am sure the div is being loaded, but the function doesn't do anything anyway.

The JavaScript and jQuery code used inside my template works fine, so the main suspect for the error is this function, which is the only one which does not work.

Comment: only `body` has onload event.

Comment: Cannot use onload  on any other elements than `body`

Comment: If you already use jQuery why don't you `$(getStatus())`? Also when polling check if websockets are an alternative for you.

Comment: Now it works, but somehow I get the same error. I'm starting to think that not all the template functions are working the way they are supposed to do...

Comment: Side-note: If you use jQuery (tagged), you are better off not using inline event handlers (like `onload=`). Use jQuery handlers as they have more features :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `onload` on body instead. I would prefer to invoke it on the `window` object like this,

```
window.onload = getStatus;
```

or to use it on `<body> .. </body>` do this:

```
<body onload="getStatus()">
 ...
</body>
```

Comment: You do realise your first comment is negated by your *two* examples? :) `body` is obviously not the *only* thing to have an `onload` event

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie even i was feeling so, updated the text a bit, check now :)

Comment: I think any element that loads its contents from an external URL has an `onload`.